# Can we tell anything at all about $ \frac {S_n^2}{\sigma^2} $ if we know that the distribution is normal?

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, sample

Suppose we don't know anything about a distribution except that it is a Normal distribution with mean $ \mu $  and variance $ \sigma^2 $.

Can we argue, theoretically, the sample variance,  $ S_n^2 $ will be close to the population variance, and thus can we say something about the ratio  $ \frac {S_n^2}{\sigma^2} $?

If this holds no basis in theory -- can we at least argue this in practice (mostly)?

Answer (score 5):

Normal distribution is fully defined by its mean and variance, that is, if you know $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ you know *everything* about the distribution.

The data points in the sample are however drawn randomly, so the sample variance will be close to $\sigma^2$ in probabilistic sense. In the case of a normal distribution $S_n^2$ follows a $\chi^2$-distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom.

I suggest looking for derivations of Student t-test, which usually cover the relation between real and measured means and variances.

Comment: hi, thanks for your help over at bio.SE.. I was creeping a bit... just a small addition: under an iid normal model, the sample variance $S_n^2 = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})^2 \sim \frac{\sigma^2}{n-1} \chi^2_{n-1}$, which from some arithmetic gives the distribution of the random variable in question. (In your response, I think you mean that $S_n^2$ follows a _scaled_ chi-square distribution.)